# Set default Php in CentOS 7

Tags: centos7, php7, roundcube

I have a centos server 7 with php 7.2 default installation. So, if I run `php-v` I  get as output :

```
PHP 7.2.34 (cli) (built: Feb  3 2021 09:23:21) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

I wanted to add addiotional php versions like 5.5 & 7.4 in ispconfig with (`yum install php74-php` and  `yum install php54-php`..) ,succeeded , but unfortunately some of my cmds , set default php version for every domain using (`www.xxx.gr/phpmyadmin` or `www.xxx.gr/webadmin` (roundcube)) to ver 5.5.38
How can I fix it back to default php 7.2 ,as it was working for so long?

Comment: I believe you must be using some extra repository such as Remi's, as the default CentOS7 does not include all of those PHP versions. Anyway, it seems this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51377847/set-default-version-of-php-in-centos-7 and the answer there should help you. The suggestion there is to switch your system default to 7.2, then use Software Collections to install the other versions for your multi-version command line needs.